# Regex to get Path ending with particular word

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

From the code below I want to get the string `/nitesh/ajax/fsafaffas+dasfaf/download-this-file'` i.e the path ending with "download-this-file".

```js
var docsa = "";
var u = '/' + docsa + '/nitesh/ajax/fsafaffas+dasfaf/download-this-file';
var uss = '/' + docsa + '/nitesh/ajax/fsafaffas+dasfaf/upload-file-here';

var ds, de;
ds = 'div_pbrasd1_datffa';
de = 'div_pfasfb1_msffg';
var d = {};
d["ff"] = midTffoken;
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it to be a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding @Mohammad Ali Rony's answer so you get the full path not just the the suffix you were looking for.

```
[\/\w+]*download-this-file\b
```

Depending on characters you want to allow in paths, add them inside the `[]`.

Actually you could just do:

```js
const path = "/nitesh/ajax/fsafaffas+dasfaf/download-this-file";
const search = "download-this-file";

if (path.indexOf(search) === path.length - search.length) {
  alert("Match: " + path)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\w*download-this-file\b
```